# Mulitiple Search in the search feild of a table view in objective c

Tags: objective-c

The requirement is that if ‘city” has been selected as the key in the  Search field then if the user enters ‘Brazil,Austria’ , then all the rows containing Brazil or Austria or both should be shown in the table.

Any help in this regard will be helpful.I am new to cocoa

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is no coding service.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide _from-scratch_ coding service. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.:-)

Comment: Before this question gets closed I'm just gonna point out, that neither Brazil, nor Austria are cities...

Answer (score 0):

Steps to follow:

1. Find how much cities are there in search using regex. (By use of ,(comma))
2. Use Predicate to find cells which contain city name.
3. Update table view cells with result of Predicate.

**Edit:**

1. Create an array of cities name

`NSArray *cities = [searchString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];`

2. Create a set of unique results

   `NSMutableSet *searchResultsSet = [NSMutableSet new];
       for(int i=0;i<[cities count];i++)
       {
           NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", [cities objectAtIndex:i]];
                   NSArray *searchResults = [recipes filteredSetUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
       [searchResultsSet addObjectsFromArray:searchResults];
       }`
3. You have final result in set `searchResultsSet`. Use it to show table view cell.

   `NSArray *searchResults = [searchResultsSet allObjects];
   [self.tableView reloadData];`

> You can also use `NSCompoundPredicate`